# Confused between inner join and left join- Building report in sql

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, left-join, inner-join

**Tables:**
[image]

**Question:** Using these table, produce a table that shows for each day in march 2020 (including weekends) & customer (for every day on or after their onboarding date), how many users were active on the product (viewing a building or creating a note), how many total buildings were viewed and how many notes were created in total. Note the customer should show up even if they were not active on that date.

**Desired Output:**

[image]

**My codes in parts:**

1. **Notes_report**

```
select date(n.created_at) "created_at", c.customer_name, count(n.user_id) "total_notes",count(distinct n.user_id) "active_user"
from customer c left join notes n on c.customer_id=n.customer_id
group by customer_name, date(created_at);
```

**Output:**

[image]

2. **Views_report**

```
select date(v.created_at) "created_at", c.customer_name, count(v.user_id) "total_views",count(distinct v.user_id) "active_user"
from customer c left join building_views v on c.customer_id=v.customer_id
group by customer_name, date(created_at);
```

**Output:**

[image]

**3) Date and customer_name:**

```
select d.date, c.customer_name
from date_spine d left join customer c on d.date>=c.onboarding_date
where d.date between '2020-03-01' and '2020-03-31';
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Where I am stuck:**

- How to combine my first code with the second code and then the resulting table with my 3rd code to come to the desired output. If this approach is not good. Please suggest a better approach.
  Please do write the code.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Read the edit help re block format for code & quotations. Give credit to quotations. Please don't **yell**. Don't ask us to write your code. [ask] [help]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Show what parts you are able to do & explain re being stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `LEFT JOIN` with the subqueries that get the counts you want from each of the other tables.

```
select d.date, c.customer_name, IFNULL(n.total_notes, 0) total_notes, IFNULL(n.active_user, 0) active_user, IFNULL(v.total_views, 0) total_views
from date_spine d 
left join customer c on d.date>=c.onboarding_date
left join (
    select date(n.created_at) date, customer_id, count(*) total_notes,count(distinct n.user_id) active_user
    from notes
    group by customer_id, date
) AS n ON n.customer_id = c.customer_id AND n.date = d.date
LEFT JOIN (
    select date(v.created_at) date, customer_id, count(*) total_views
    from building_views v
    group by customer_id, date
) AS v ON v.customer_id = c.customer_id AND v.date = d.date
where d.date between '2020-03-01' and '2020-03-31'
```

The subqueries don't need to join with `customer`, since only the main query needs to do that to get the name. The subqueries just use the customer ID.